# Couldn't connect to oracle db 19 from virtualbox

Tags: java, linux, oracle, oracle19c, oraclelinux

My host machine is Ubuntu 20.04. I have an installed Oracle 8.5 tty version on my VirtualBox which I used oracle database 19.3.0. I have a bridge connection to my Oracle Linux and a second adapter as a 'host-only adapter'. I configured my listener - listener.ora in the following way.
(test.max.com is my hostname)

[image]

and my tnsnames.ora

[image]

I checked my port 1521 whether it is open or not.
I used this command.
`netstat -an | grep $1521`
[image]

then I tried to connect java from my host machine(Ubuntu), I used the 'thin' client option, via bridge adapter. So I was stuck on a 'The network adapter could not establish connection' error.

P.S. I also tried the connection using a host-only adapter, before connecting I used the ping command IP of the host-only adapter, but it froze and it didn't show anything.

Comment: Don't have an answer for your specific issue, but if you're just trying to get this working for local development, have you considered using Docker instead? I've been able to spin up an Oracle docker instance pretty easily. https://github.com/oracle/docker-images

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, I did consider this approach but I couldn't figure out, how to deploy it.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, Can you provide me with some guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### host/guest connectivity issues

Suggesting you have some network connectivity problem from your vm-host to your vm-guest.

1. In vm-host open firewall port 1521 for outgoing/outbound packets.
2. In vm-guest open firewall port 1521 for incoming/inbound packets.

In vm-guest run `ip a` command, to identify the IP4 addresses of vm-guest.

3. I suggest to test connectivity from vm-host to vm-quest using `ping` command on each vm-guest IP4 address.

Once you have network connectivity established.

4. Check Oracle's network listener status in vm-guest  using `lsnrctl status`  tool documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/lsnrctl.htm).

#### Use containter instead of a vm

Assuming your vm-host is Linux machine, suggesting to load a prepared Docker container installed and configured with Oracle database from [Oracle](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:1:13445639575971:::1:P1_BUSINESS_AREA:3&cs=33sm5SHHLZkGyjqgw1lNdsDI9WbK2bebxe2AoEROECipleVqCt3Wl7YKZIem_b-vefoie-WgKlB6e7X-Fr13QLQ) or [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe).